# JUnit and file write access

Tags: java, file, junit, ioexception

So I have a method to write a string to a file:

```
 public static void saveStringToFile(String path, String string) {

    File file = new File(path);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    FileWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileWriter(path);
        out.write(string);
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And my test class with the following setUp method which runs before each test (to delete the testfile before each one):

```
public static final String TEST_FILE = "somefile.xml";
```

//...

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws IOException {
    if (MyCustomClass.fileExists(TEST_FILE)) {
        new File(TEST_FILE).delete();
    }
}
```

Each of my test tries to write something to the file using the method `saveStringToFile()`. It succeeds like for a couple of times, but a some random point I finally get the `java.io.IOException: Access is denied`. Got no idea why this happens - sometimes it occurs in test1, sometimes in test3...

It was working OK, when I was using Java7 FileIO, but I needed to migrate back to Java6...

Comment: How are you executing the tests?  Is it possible your test runner is running them in parallel and the tests are stepping on each other trying to access the file?

Comment: add synchronized blocks.

Comment: I am running it with Eclipse > Run as JUnit test... As suspected that the test may be run in parrallel - how can I verify this and what can I do with it?

Comment: See my answer below, you shouldn't be unit testing your file system or test runner parallelism :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, probably JUnit wasn't running it parrallel, cause as I suppose It doesn't do it by default.

The problem was in my `readfile` method:

```
private String readFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return (new Scanner(new File(path))).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
}
```

To work fine I had to fix

```
private String readFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = (new Scanner(new File(path)));
    String s = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    scanner.close();
    return s;
}
```

The `close()` method for `Scanner` was the key...

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing that you are *able to* create, write to and delete a file, or are you testing *what* is written to the file?

If the latter, then perhaps you should be mocking/overriding the `saveStringToFile( ... )` method and instead focus on verifying that the code you're unit testing actually produces the correct output.

If the former, then I quite agree with @Omaha's suggestion that your test runner is likely running several tests in parallel.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's some problems with the exception handling. The call to `out.close()` should be within a separate try-catch block inside a finally block. If an exception is thrown when writing to the file, the file is never closed.

I would recommend looking at something like Apache Commons IO which has many useful IO methods like `FileUtils.writeStringToFile()`.